# How to remove links between cells in Excel?

Tags: excel-2010

When I copy a certain table from one sheet in MS Excel and paste it to another sheet an issue arise. The issue is that if I write in one cell, automatically the same cell in the other sheet is changed with the new figure. For e.g if I have written 5 in cell A3, automatically 5 gets written in A3 in the other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but probably you have formula copied with reference to previous sheet.

On copy/paste event, Excel takes multiple items (values, style, formulas, links,...). Because of that Excel has a possibility to paste just selected items. You can achieve that with:

1. Copy selected range of cells
2. Right click on cell where you want to paste values
3. Select "Paste special"
4. Window with paste options will pop out
5. Select what you want to paste (eg. Values)
6. Click "OK" and you are done

Hope, that it helps!